# Using 'cmd /c dir' vs 'dir'

Tags: java, cmd

Using the method

```
public Process exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir) throws IOException
```

I am supposed to print the output of the command `dir [filepath]` but using Java,
and my question is, why do I have to type for the command argument, `(cmd /c dir)`, and not just `(dir)`?

If I type `dir [filepath]` in command prompt for Windows, it works, but not in Java.

Comment: The real question is why you're exec-ing *anything* rather than using `File.listFiles()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exec() executes new process, and for that you need executable file to run (i.e. some .exe file, if we talk about Windows). But there is no "dir.exe". "dir" is built-in command of the Windows Command Prompt, cmd.exe, so to run it, you need to run cmd.exe and pass such command to it.

In contrast, for example, in Linux, `ls` is separate executable, so there you can directly do something like `ls /home/myuser` instead of `sh -c 'ls /home/myuser'`.